# How to invalidate a specific memory page that belongs to a specific process

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

I would like to add a function to the Linux kernel that, given a process id and a virtual memory address, the function invalidates the page that belongs to that process and contains that memory address.

Basically, I would like to force the process into a page fault if it tries to access that page.

I do not want to use cache thrashing or anything of that sort. I want my function to be very clinical in terms of wasting the process's time. For example, I do not want to flush the whole tlb or anything like that.

Sorry guys for not including what I have already tried. But I have tried a lot. Any ideas on how to do this are very welcome and much appreciated.

**Update:**

I saw that there are these functions:

```
flush_cache_all()
flush_cache_mm(mm)
flush_cache_dup_mm(mm)
flush_cache_range(vma, start, end)
flush_cache_page(vma, vmaddr, pfn)
flush_dcache_page(page)
flush_icache_range(start, end)
flush_icache_page(vma,pg)
```

But I am not sure which ones are available to the x86-64 architecture. I do not see their implementation of this specific architecture.

Comment: Your question is so focused that you might not get useful answers. It would probably be helpful if you explained your ultimate goal, so if there are other ways of accomplishing it somebody can point them out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the same as the `mprotect` syscall (see `mm/mprotect.c`), only for a process different from `current`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But can you please more specific? what is there that I need to be digging into. I have already looked at this and is saw at one point the  function `__mmu_notifier_invalidate_range_start()` being called...is this what you mean? From reading about this function, I see its purpose is to inform a guest machine (VM) about events happening in the host machine...so it may not be what I am looking for. I did not find anything else interesting.

Comment: The `mprotect` syscall already does what you want, you just have to replace `current` with the `task_struct` of the desired process.

Comment: oohhh....as I am writing this I started to realize what you meant. So, you mean something like calling mprotect on that specific page, but with the already existing page protection flags?
I also saw it calls the `flush_cache_range()` and `flush_tlb_range()`...are these functions supported in the x86-64 arch?

Comment: And btw, yes I need the task struct be other than `current` ... but that is easy to modify.

Comment: `mprotect` is a system call that works on every architecture (with an MMU).